# Can not rip audio cd with pacpl perl error

Tags: debian, audio-cd

I'm using debian bookworm with mate desktop.
I try to rip a few files from different audio cd.

```
pacpl --rip 1 --nocddb  --device=/dev/sr0 -to mp3 /home/alex/Musik/Singles/
cannot connect to cddb db: freedb.freedb.org:8880 [Invalid argument] at /usr/share/perl5/CDDB_get.pm line 310.
```

I do not need the connection to cddb. But I can not figured out where to set the option

```
--nocddb
```

correct in my command.

Comment: Have you tried with --noinput instead or alongside --nocddb ?

Comment: I tried both now `--noinput` alone and together with `--nocddb` saddly sam error.

Comment: --noinput should have disabled any CDDB interactivity which apparently is enabled by default.

Comment: My device is spinning up but the perl error persits. I tried to set both option to different places in my command. And according to manpage `--noinput` is enabled by default.